# Knowledge to attack Miklos Schweitzer problems - number theory

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

I would like to know what should I know in number theory to be able to attack Miklos Schweitzer's number theory problems.

If anyone can list out the knowledge I need to have in order to attack these problems, it would be very nice.

Comment: Any reference for these problems?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~mmaroti/schweitzer/

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miklós_Schweitzer_Competition). Also look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3253_mikls_schweitzer); and the [book](https://books.google.at/books?id=3f7ZBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA570&lpg=PA570&dq=Miklos+Schweitzer+problems++number+theory&source=bl&ots=pa7JJoMbnS&sig=JnUzVSTgUgdkTYMDJFaQoNEpZ98&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit6qPDloTUAhVEAZoKHeg5CzQQ6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=Miklos%20Schweitzer%20problems%20%20number%20theory&f=false) with solutions.